# Distance Calculation Not Working

Tags: python, list, math, distance

Using Python, I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points, and what I've written isn't working.
I have two lists with two elements per row, effectively lists of coordinates, and I'm trying to use pythagoras to work out their seperations, and if they are close enough then print them.
I have:

```
import math

for i in range(len(a)):           #a and c are imported lists
    for j in range(len(c)):
        y = b[i, 0] - d[j ,0]     #b and d are the actual lists, they have been cleaned up so they can be used
        z = b[i, 1] - d[j, 1]

        def f(y, z): (math.sqrt((y**2) + (z**2)))
        if f <= 0.0056:
            print i, j, b[i, 0], b[i, 1], d[j, 0], d[j, 1], f
```

Thank you!

Comment: What language is this? It looks like you're declaring some kind of inline function (`f`) but there's no obvious place that you call this function and it looks like you're comparing the function object itself (`f`) with a number. Of course, that could be wrong, but that's why you should add a language tag.

Comment: I'm using Python, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Then it looks like the rest of my comments are probably correct - you're defining the `f` function but you never invoke it and thus never actually compute the distance. You then compare the *function* `f` with `0.0056`.

Comment: I just tried Tobias' suggestion, and it works as long as I remove the "if" line. I'm not sure how to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- your function does not return anything
- you never call your function.

When using `def` to define a function, you have to use `return` to return the result:

```
def f(y, z): return math.sqrt(y**2 + z**2)
```

Alternatively, when using `lambda`, the `return` is implicit:

```
f = lambda y, z: math.sqrt(y**2 + z**2)
```

Then, you still need to call the function (`f <= 0.0056` compares the function *itself* to the number)

```
dist = f(y, z)
if dist <= 0.0056:
        print i, j, b[i, 0], b[i, 1], d[j, 0], d[j, 1], dist
```

Or, since you are using the function only this one time, just drop the function definition entirely:

```
 dist = math.sqrt(y**2 + z**2)
 if dist <= 0.0056:
     print i, j, b[i, 0], b[i, 1], d[j, 0], d[j, 1], dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an `b` and `d` like this:

```
b = ((1,1),(2,2))
d = ((1.001,1),(2,2))
```

The following code:

```
import math
import itertools

for point_a, point_b in itertools.product(b, d):
    y = point_a[0] - point_b[0]
    z = point_a[1] - point_b[1]
    distance = math.sqrt((y**2) + (z**2))
    if distance < 0.0056:
        print "%s => %s: %s" % (point_a, point_b, distance)
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 1) => (1.001, 1): 0.001
(2, 2) => (2, 2): 0.0
```